# How can a loaded LGBM model produces different predictions on different machines?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scikit-learn

I have previously saved LGBM model with `pickle`. The program takes the content from the given web page, then classifies it.

Loaded model works well in my local computers (a desktop and a laptop). But it gives nonsense predictions when it runs on an EC2 instance. What issue can cause this?

- The models are exactly the same in three machines (desktop, laptop and EC2 instance)
- The input data of the model (after the preprocessing steps) are the same
- The codes are the same (cloned by Git)
- The predictions does make sense on local machines
- The `numpy`, `scikit-learn` and other package versions are the same in all three machines

I load the model with:

```
self.mapper = pickle.load(open(model_path + "mapper.pkl", "rb"))
self.model = pickle.load(open(model_path + "model.pkl", "rb"))
```

And do predictions with, in case you wonder (sorry for the messy code, this part didn't written by me):

```
data = self.pipeline.transform([{"url_name": url}])
df = pd.DataFrame({"text": [data]})

processed = self.mapper.transform(df)
processed = [a[0] for a in processed]

ws_results = OrderedDict()
for p1, p2 in sorted(zip(self.classes, self.model.predict_proba(processed).tolist()[0]), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])[:3]:
            ws_results[p1] = round(p2, 3)
```

Comment: Is the complete environment (all the library versions, python version, etc) exact same on all the machines?

Comment: @VivekKumar Yes, I use pipenv with the same Pipfile

Comment: What does nonsense predictions mean? Example outputs on same datasets?

Comment: That sorted thing is highly suspicious. It seems to be sorting one the output predictions. Those are floating point numbers, and unlikely to sort in a meaningful way. Move the `preds = predict_proba()` part out and check whether `preds` are the same